# Classifier output range of values in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

I have a model saved as a pickle file.

Now assuming the model was trained to predict a label from 5 possible labels. How can I check which values (labels) the model can predict?

I do not want my model to predict a value based on X_Test. I want to know the possible values that the model is *capable* of predicting.

EDIT to add more details

```
def predict_model():
    vectorizer_reloaded = cPickle.load(open('model.pkl','rb'))
    detector_reloaded = cPickle.load(open('model_clf.pkl','rb'))
    X_test = vectorizer_reloaded.transform(df['Text'])
    xs = detector_reloaded.predict(X_test)
    prob_pos = detector_reloaded.predict_proba(X_test)
```

I'm using above code to predict the output...
xs contains the predicted outputs but is there also a way to get all outputs in model with something like this

All_Outputs = detector_reloaded.all_outputs()

Comment: Welcome o stack overflow! You haven't really given enough detail for us to know how to answer. Have you checked the documentation for the model you're using? For example, [sklearn's logisitic regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) has an attribute `classes_: ndarray of shape (n_classes, ) A list of class labels known to the classifier.`

Comment: Thanks, I've added more details and some code i'm using..

Comment: This code unfortunately doesn't tell us what model you're actually using. What about the output of `print(detector_reloaded )`? That would at least tell you which docs to check

Comment: ```SVC(C=1000, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
  decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma=0.001, kernel='rbf',
  max_iter=-1, probability=True, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
  tol=0.001, verbose=False)
```
The output is as pasted above...

Comment: There it is! You're using a sklearn [support vector classifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC). You can see the docs at that link, including the attribute `classes_` is included

Comment: not sure how i can use it on existing model?
Is there something like print(detector_reloaded.classes_)

Comment: Have you tried that? (Hint: That's exactly it)

Comment: OMG yes thats it.
I thought i tried it and got error but now i realised i had used it on xs & prob_pos instead of detector reloaded... been stuck on this for hours because of this stupidity..
Thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

This is very often in a field called `classes_`. I haven’t checked exhaustively, and it’s not required in the [base classifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.base.ClassifierMixin.html#sklearn.base.ClassifierMixin), but it’s a decent first place to look.

```
detector_reloaded = cPickle.load(open('model_clf.pkl','rb'))
print(detector_reloaded.classes_)
```

Note that I found this even for classifiers that can perform multi-label classification like DecisionTreeClassifier.

Classes I saw `classes_` in:

- [KNeighborsClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier)
- [SVC](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC)
- [GaussianProcessClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessClassifier.html#sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessClassifier)
- [DecisionTreeClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier)
- [RandomForestClassifer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier)
- [AdaBoostClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier)
- [MLPClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html#sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier)
- [GaussianNB](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB)
- [QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.discriminant_analysis.QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis.html#sklearn.discriminant_analysis.QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis)

This list isn’t exhaustive, so be sure to check the documentation for your particular model to verify whether it sets `classes_`.

Comment: i'm confused with the documentation.. is there an example.. i've added some code i'm using to predict..

Comment: Yes, I’ve updated my code to match what you added to your question.